# Send PDF Attachment of Active Sheet with Email Cell Reference in Same Active Sheet

Tags: email, pdf, google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to send the active sheet and only the active sheet as a pdf attachment to an email located in cell C1 or (1,3)

The current script executes but I receive no email.

```
function sendSheetToPdf(){
}
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
var email = sheet.getRange(1,3).getValue();

// Base URL
var url = "mysheetsurl", ss.getId());

/* Specify PDF export parameters
From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
 */

var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
     + '&size=A4' // paper size legal / letter / A4
     + '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
     + '&fitw=true&source=labnol' // fit to page width, false for actual size
     + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
     + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
     + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
     + '&gid='; // the sheet's Id

var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {                                 
        headers : {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    }).getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf");

sheet_as_pdf_blob_document=response;


// Email Business
var recipient = email;
var subject="Test"
var body="TEST.";
var nameOfSender="Test";

// Here we send the email

function sendReport() {
 
   var message = {
    to: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    name: nameOfSender,
    attachments: [sheet_as_pdf_blob_document]
  }

   MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

I've written scripts that sent emails before successfully but never without designating the sheet name and email address. This time I wanted to create a dynamic way to send emails based on the active sheet. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issues in your current code:

1. Your function structure is not correct. Your code should show you failed execution logs upon running this in your editor.

**Here is what it looks like:**

```
function sendSheetToPdf(){
}

// process the sheet data and get pdf blob

function sendReport() {

  //send email
}
```

2. Your base url is incorrect. Based on your reference material [Specify PDF export parameters](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579), your base url should be like this:

   `var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + doc.getId() + "/export?`

---

### Sample Working Code:

```
function sendSheetToPdf(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  var email = sheet.getRange(1,3).getValue();

  // Base URL
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ss.getId()+"/export?";
  
  /* Specify PDF export parameters
  From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
  */

  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
      + '&size=A4' // paper size legal / letter / A4
      + '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true&source=labnol' // fit to page width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
      + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
      + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
      + '&gid='; // the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {                                 
          headers : {
              'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
          }
      }).getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf");

  var sheet_as_pdf_blob_document=response;


  // Email Business
  var recipient = email;
  var subject="Test"
  var body="TEST.";
  var nameOfSender="Test";

  // Here we send the email

  var message = {
  to: recipient,
  subject: subject,
  body: body,
  name: nameOfSender,
  attachments: [sheet_as_pdf_blob_document]
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
   
}
```

- I just fixed your `base url`, move `sendReport()` content inside `sendSheetToPdf()` because the variables needed to send the email were declared inside `sendSheetToPdf()`.

### Output:

[image]